# Is there any difference between these 2 models when it's implemented DB and constraints?

Tags: sql

[image]

I am learning fundamental SQL, I am confused between these 2 models. Is there any difference between these 2 models when it's implemented DB and constraints?

they both mean A link to many B(many relationship). Staff has many phones and custormer has many accounts

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but it looks like 1) a staff has a phone. 2) a customer has many accounts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Crow’s foot notation in entity-relationship diagrams.

Please let me know if I am wrong.

For Model 1:- It represents "One and only one" relationship, i.e No more than one relationship is possible between instances.

- It indicates that a staff has a phone.

For Model 2:- It represents "One or many" relationship, i.e The “one” indicates that this is not an optional relationship, although there might be more than one.

- It indicates that a customer has many accounts.

Comment: no, they are botgh mean A link to many B. Staff has many phone and User has many account

Comment: Yes there is a difference between both the model. For more detail please follow the [link](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/#:~:text=In%20crow's%20foot%20notation%3A,represented%20by%20an%20empty%20circle.)

Answer (score 0):

In your case,

1. A staff can have only one phone. It is one - one relationship.
2. A Customer can have many accounts. It is one - many relationship.

To ensure one-one relationship, you can keep parent primary key as the primary key for child also. It is called identifying relationship.

- Staff

  - StaffId - Primary Key
  - Staff Attributes ...
- Phone

  - StaffId - Primary key coming from Staff table
  - Phone Attributes ...

To have one - many relationship, a account can exist on its own. It will be mapped to a customer. It is called non-identifying relationship.

- Customer

  - CustomerId - Primary Key
  - Customer Attributes ...
- Account

  - AccountId - Primary Key
  - CustomerId - Foreign Key coming from Customer Table
  - Account Attributes ...